# How can I schedule posts to Instagram with the Javascript Graph API?

Tags: api, facebook

I manage to schedule a facebook post with the API, but how do I schedule a Instagram post?

This is scheduling a post to Facebook. And to be able to do so you have to use:

```
published: false,
scheduled_publish_time: convertedtime
```

So I use the above code in below to be able to schedule.

```
FB.api('/' + pageId + '/photos', 'post', {
        message :facebooktexten,
        link : lanken, 
        url : bildUrl,
        access_token : aToken,
        published: false,
        scheduled_publish_time: convertedtime
        }, function(response) {             
            if (!response || response.error) {
                app.dialog.alert('Error occured'+response.error);           
            } else {                            
        }
});
```

But when I try to do the same for Instagram it posts directly to Instagram.
First I get the container Id and then I post with that container Id. But should I have

```
published: false,
scheduled_publish_time: convertedtime
```

when I request the container Id or when I post it?

```
FB.api('/' + instagramId + '/media?image_url='+bildUrl+'&caption='+instagramtexten, 'post', {
        published: false,
        scheduled_publish_time: convertedtime
            }, function(response) {
                                                        
            if (!response || response.error) {                              
                app.dialog.alert('Error occured'+response.message);
            } else {
                //first I get the container Id here----                                 
                console.log('Media Container ID: '+response.id)
                
                FB.api('/' + instagramId + '/media_publish?creation_id='+response.id, 'post', {
                    published: false,
                    scheduled_publish_time: convertedtime
                    }, function(response) {

                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        app.dialog.alert('Error occured'+response.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log('It is posted!!!')
                    }
            });
        }
});
```

Or how do you schedule to Instagram?
Also where do I see scheduled post in Facebook?
I thought that I would see it in the business pages where you see all your posts but I can´t see it there? Maybe because my app is still in review perhaps?

Comment: _“Or how do you schedule to Instagram?”_ – you would _start_ by consulting the API documentation, to figure out whether what you want is even offered as a possibility (instead of rather naively assuming, that it “must be”.)

Comment: Haha my god!! What do you think I have been doing? How do you think that I got the above code!! Jesus! And yes it is possible according to the latest news about the Instagram API!

Comment: So where are those latest news then, link?

Comment: Here is the link where it says that you can schedule post to Instagram via the API. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/01/26/introducing-instagram-content-publishing-api/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=fb4d-newsletter-february21&utm_campaign=organic&utm_offering=business-tools&utm_product=instagram&utm_content=body-button-instagram-graph-API&utm_location=2

Comment: I can see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/ mentioning the word “schedule” only once, and the other endpoint descriptions it refers to, don’t appear to be mentioning the topic at all. Guess you’d have to ask Facebook, how that is supposed to work, resp. where it is actually documented.

Answer (score 1):

While the Facebook Graph API allows scheduling, the new Instagram Graph API currently doesn't.

The overall content publishing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

And if you want to add media, first create an [IG Media Object Container](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#create) and then [publish the container](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media_publish#creating).

As you can see, the first version of the Instagram API is pretty simple and has no scheduling capabilities. I expect future versions will support additional capabilities. However, given the restriction of 25 Instagram posts every 24-rolling-hour-period, it might be difficult for them to allow scheduled posts via their API.

You could also look at third party social media APIs that offer future scheduling.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, I have already got normal posting to work, I just thought it is strange that they have scheduling as a new big thing in their newsletter to developers and then they don´t have any docs about it. I just have to wait and see if they release it, hopefully soon :-)

Comment: I agree. At first glance the announcement looks like the API allows scheduled posts. However, the wording, esp in the Content Publishing API, indicates you can schedule posts yourself using the API.

Comment: Yes and I got scheduling to work to Facebook, but not to Instagram. Well I guess it will come in the future.